# JDO - Should I use detachCopy or makeTransient?

Tags: java, jdo

With JDO, when should I use detachCopy and when should I use makeTransient?

What exactly do each of them do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure we wrote docs about those things ...
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/performance_tuning.html
though obviously the JDO spec defines them way better

Comment: I had read that link you sent earlier, but was still unsure. I was thinking of just using makeTransient all the time, I don't really know when I would want to use detachCopy since its more expensive.

Comment: The link is borken,   @DataNucleus will you fix it or quote the key summary here ?

Answer (score 0):

From http://db.apache.org/jdo/attach_detach.html

> *A detached object retains the id of its datastore entity. Detached objects should be used where you want to update the objects and attach
>   them later (updating the associated object in the datastore. If you
>   want to create copies of the objects in the datastore with their own
>   identities you should use makeTransient instead of detachCopy.*